# add items to panel and columns to grid dynamically

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-grid

I am using ExtJs 4.1 and trying to add items to panel and columns to grid dynamically.

My Requirement

MainPanel `(Ext.panel.Panel)` has 2 child items:

- DynamicPanel `(Ext.panel.Panel)`

  1. I want to add this panel to the main panel dynamically.
  2. Then... I want to add items to DynamicPanel dynamically, the items  are a config  of the **MainPanel** called : "elements"
- DynamicGrid `(Ext.grid.Panel)`

  1. I want to again, add this to the main panel dynamically.
  2. I want to add columns to DynamicGrid dynamically, and again these columns are part of the **MainPanel** config gridcolumns.

I am getting the below error:

> this.dpanel is undefined
>   [Break On This Error] this.dpanel.add(this.elements)

My code is as below:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'date', 'time'],
    data: {
        'items': [{
            "name": "Lisa",
                "email": "[EMAIL="
            lisa@simpsons.com "]lisa@simpsons.com[/EMAIL]",
                "phone": "555-111-1224",
                "date": "12/21/2012",
                "time": "12:22:33"
        }, {
            "name": "Bart",
                "email": "[EMAIL="
            bart@simpsons.com "]bart@simpsons.com[/EMAIL]",
                "phone": "555-222-1234",
                "date": "12/21/2012",
                "time": "12:22:33"
        }, {
            "name": "Homer",
                "email": "[EMAIL="
            home@simpsons.com "]home@simpsons.com[/EMAIL]",
                "phone": "555-222-1244",
                "date": "12/21/2012",
                "time": "12:22:33"
        }, {
            "name": "Marge",
                "email": "[EMAIL="
            marge@simpsons.com "]marge@simpsons.com[/EMAIL]",
                "phone": "555-222-1254",
                "date": "12/21/2012",
                "time": "12:22:33"
        }]
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});
Ext.define('DynamicGridPanel', {
    extends: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.dynamicGridPanel',
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1
    })],
    height: 200,
    width: 200
});

Ext.define('DynamicPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.dynamicPanel',
    title: 'DynamicAdd',
    width: 200,
    height: 200
});
Ext.define('MainPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.dynamicMainPanel',
    title: 'MainPanel',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 600,
    height: 600,
    constructor: function (config) {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);
        me.dpanel = Ext.create('DynamicPanel');
        me.dgridpanel = Ext.create('DynamicGridPanel');
        me.items = [this.dpanel, this.dgridpanel];
    }, //eo constructor
    onRender: function () {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);
        //I am getting  error at the below lines saying the dpanel and dynamicGridPanel  undefined
        me.dpanel.add(this.elements);
        me.dynamicGridPanel.columns.add(this.gridcolumns);
    }
});
var panel1 = Ext.create('MainPanel', {
    gridcolumns: [{
        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
        width: 42,
        dataIndex: 'notes',
        processEvent: function () {
            return false;
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        header: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        editor: 'textfield'
    }, {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        header: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            allowBlank: false
        }
    }, {
        header: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }, {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        header: 'Date',
        dataIndex: 'date',
        flex: 1,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'datetextfield',
            allowBlank: false
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        header: 'Time',
        dataIndex: 'time',
        flex: 1,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'timetextfield',
            allowBlank: false
        }
    }],
    elements: [{
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        width: 70,
        tabIndex: 1,
        fieldLabel: 'Account No',
        itemId: 'acctno',
        labelAlign: 'top'
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        itemId: 'lastname',
        width: 90,
        tabIndex: 2,
        fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
        labelAlign: 'top'
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        itemId: 'firstname',
        width: 100,
        tabIndex: 3,
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        labelAlign: 'top'
    }]
});
```

Comment: @Reimius The reason i have put code because it is not working and i have tried a lot, if its basic then its better you help me out by sending  link or answering rather than just downvoting, because that will help you getting good reputation score and if ur answer is correct i will definitily mark it as answer.

Comment: @Reimius thanks buddy for repeatedly viewing my forum qts and taking such a pain to answer for all the messages posted by me even though you thought it was not worth answering (or was it that you too were looking for the answer and so asked for extra bounty points) anyways got the answer and really appreciate your efforts for not answering and arguing on the same.all the best....

Comment: I only made that comment after you didn't mark the below answer correct, but it seems you figured out he was right.  I up-voted that answer lol.

Comment: +1. And I hope you learned a lesson Reimius.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the child elements in initComponent:

```
initComponent: function() {
   var me = this;
   me.dpanel = Ext.create('DynamicPanel');
   me.dgridpanel = Ext.create('DynamicGridPanel');
   me.items = [this.dpanel, this.dgridpanel]; 
   me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

Dont forget to define the require config for columns in your grid:

```
columns: []
```

Look at that Example here for adding dynamically columns in grid http://neiliscoding.blogspot.de/2011/09/extjs4-dynamically-add-columns.html